# How can i get a view position from an another meditator class?

Tags: actionscript-3, robotlegs

My startup command is:

```
var containerView:ContainerView = new ContainerView();
var sampleView:SampleView = new SampleView();

contextView.addChild(containerView);
contextView.addChild(sampleView);

containerView.y = 50;
containerView.x = 250;
```

SampleMediator:

```
[Inject]
public var containerView:ContainerView;

trace(containerView.x); //0
```

Main:

```
public class Main extends Context
{
    public function Main(contextView:DisplayObjectContainer)
    {
        super(contextView);
    }

    override public function startup():void
    {
        commandMap.mapEvent(ContextEvent.STARTUP_COMPLETE, StartupCommand, ContextEvent, true);

        injector.mapSingleton(SampleView);

        mediatorMap.mapView(ContainerView, ContainerMediator);
        mediatorMap.mapView(SampleView, SampleMediator);

        super.startup();
    }
}
```

So how can find exact position of containerView in another class? Everytime it returns 0.

Comment: You could check if the two `ContainerView` are the same instance. Try to set and trace the `name` property.

Comment: How? can you explain a little bit more :)

Comment: Before going further, can you post your context definition?

Comment: Its built-in class which is in robotlegs frame work. I didnt use custom class. http://api.robotlegs.org/org/robotlegs/mvcs/Context.html#contextView

Comment: I know but, can you post your context definition?

Comment: are you calling trace(containerView.x); from onRegister() ?